# HQL select query on @ManyToMany mapped entity produces invalid SQL syntax

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hql

There are a bunch of questions here about queries on HQL many-to-many mapped tables but I have looked quite a bit and have not seen this one.

I have two tables in a many-to-many relationship with the source and destination tables mapped as entities and the @ManyToMany relationship defined between them, configured as is commonly recommended.

The twist is that I am trying to query on these tables so that I can get the values for both the source and destination keys in a single query. The reason is for performance, we have deeply nested hierarchical data and to get all of the related data via vanilla Hibernate results in dozens or hundreds of queries which doesn't perform adequately. Instead I intend on fetching all of the data at once and mapping it in code.

Here are sample class definitions:

```
@Entity
public class This {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @Column
    protected Long otherId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "this_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "that_id")})
    private List<That> thats;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class That {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The HQL is this:

```
select t.id,t.thats from This t where t.otherId=13
```

And here is the SQL that gets produced:

```
select
    this0_.id as col_0_0_,
    . as col_1_0_,
    that2_.id as id1_59_,
    that2_.name as name2_59_ 
from
    this this0_ 
inner join
    this_thats thats1_ 
        on this0_.id=thats1_.this_id 
inner join
    that that2_ 
        on thats1_.that_id=that2_.id 
where
    this0_.other_id=13
```

As you can see, the 2nd column in the `select` clause is invalid, it looks as though it is trying to create a column but does not use a valid column name or alias and somewhat surprisingly produces a SQL statement of invalid syntax that fails when it is executed.  I have stepped through the SQL generation code and turned on trace logging but can't figure out what it's trying to do or how to fix it.

If I delete that 2nd column, this query runs fine and returns exactly the data I'm looking for. As an alternative I've considered implementing this in native SQL, but I'd like to avoid this and stick with HQL if possible for consistency across the rest of the project.

Another option I tried was `select t,t.thats ...`. This did produce a valid query, but, not shown in this example, it issued a lot more queries for other relationships that are eagerly fetched from the `This` entity which also kills the performance. I really need to fetch just the single key column from the source table.

The really minimal query that would return the data that I need would not have to hit the `That` table at all, it would be only on the `This` table and the implicit, unmapped `this_thats` table which is created and managed by JPA but is not mapped to an entity. I tried mapping this to an entity so that I could query on it but Hibernate complained on startup that this table was mapped twice.  If there is some other way to get at this table and query it directly I'd be happy to do that.

This is with hibernate-jpa-2.1 which I know is an old version but this is a legacy system in production. If upgrading the version of JPA would help I'd consider it but would like to understand the root cause first if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, which I'm posting to help anyone else who runs into this.  The `join` needs to be explicit in the HQL like this:

```
select t.id,th from This t join t.thats th where t.otherId=13
```

Apparently Hibernate can't figure out the correct select statement without this.

Answer (score 1):

While working with spring data jpa simply use findAll on repository to get List

But if you want HQL approach try below one

Add below method to repository

```
@Query("select new ThisThat(u.id, u.otherId,th.name), "
            "from This u " +
            "inner join this_thats l on l.this_id=u.id " +
            "inner join that th on th.id=l.that.id " +
            "where u.id=:id)
List<ThisAndThat> getThisAndThat(long id);
```

create a class with name ThisAndThat as below

```
class ThisAndThat{
long id;
long otherId;
String name;
.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this old version of hibernate but I would try to replace

```
    {@JoinColumn(name = "this_id")} by {@JoinColumn(name = "this.id")}
```

and

```
    {@JoinColumn(name = "that_id")} by {@JoinColumn(name = "that.id")}
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with it either but the outcome is that it creates a table with the default name for a join table in this case "this_thats" and the two column names that are specified "this_id" and "that_id" in other words this is a way of specifying the names of the columns of the join table. I don't think it has to do with the problem I'm having though, I tried making this change and got the same result. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Just another try: maybe the problem is, that you can´t get a list as a single line of result of a SQL select statement. Maybe you have not to select the second column because the

```
    List<That> thats
```

is filled automatically by hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying or trying to do doesn't make sense. `t.thats` is a collection so you cannot return it as part of a row. You need to think more object oriented with JPA. Also, JPA 2.1 isn't particularly out of date so there should be no problem there. So, a working query that prefetches the collection of `thats` is done like so:

```
This t2 = em.createQuery("from This t left outer join fetch t.thats where t.otherId = 12", This.class).getSingleResult();
System.out.println("" + t2 + t2.getThats());
```

This query tells JPA to get the `This` you want and any related `thats` in a single query.

You state that you want only the contents of the `ThisThat` join table. That table only has the `ids` of the relations. For some reason you may want the ids so you can do the fetch of the `thats` later. Fair enough but like you said you would have to create the join table as a separate entity and then use a query that `joins` only that entity. It is quite possible but it is also a separate question and you should try more to do it on your own first.

For completeness sake you have modeled a `unidirectional` ManyToMany mapping owned by the `This` entity.

Comment: Not sure why `select t.thats...` doesn't make sense because it produces a perfectly valid query that fetches some of the data that I need, it fetches the two columns from the `That` table and the result list is a List of `That` objects which are related to my `This` object. The other piece of information I need in the results is the `id` of the `This` object related to each `That` which I am trying to add to the select clause. This is perfectly valid in SQL, and as is so often the case I know exactly what I need to do in SQL but spend a lot of time trying to get Hibernate to do it.

Comment: How is that not what you are getting from the above query?